# rethinkDB binary from database to byte[]

Tags: java, binary, rethinkdb

This is the first time I stored binaries in rethinkdb and it went quiet well for storing them. The approach was quite simple (as documented in the command reference of [ReQl](https://rethinkdb.com/api/java/binary/). Also retrieving the binary from the Database again is fairly easy, yet I am struggling to convert it into a `byte[]`. The documentation says that `r.binary()` should return `byte[]` but in my case it returns a `MapObject` with a key called `data`. When retrieving that, `data` is an `object` but cannot be casted to `byte[]`.

My code

```
MapObject mo = (MapObject)r.binary(continents.get("visibleMapImageBinary")).build(); 
//^^ is the MapObject that I can retrieve
String b = (String)tempor.get("data");
```

However I do not know how to get this back into a `byte[]`. Also tried to convert the String into a byte array, which also failed.

Thanks for any advice :)

Answer (score 0):

After some trying out (and googling for what `[B` is, which I just thought stood for nothing but actually is the primtive of `byte[]`). This is my solution, no need to `build()` or even cast to the MapObject.

```
byte[] temp = (byte[])continents.get("visibleMapImageBinary");
```

I actually thought I tried this before, but it seems like I didn't ... well :)